# Could not locate runnable browser

Tags: python, ubuntu, browser, chromium, runnable

I'm trying to open up a browser using python but could not open it. I'm trying to open "chromium" on Ubuntu which I already have on my computer.

`

```
mymap = pygmaps.pygmaps(lat, lng, 18) 
mymap.addpoint(lat, lng)
mymap.draw('./mymap.draw.html')
mybrowser = webbrowser.get('chromium')
mybrowser.open_new_tab('./mymap.draw.html')
```

`

I get this error.

```
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

Comment: Have you installed the Chromium driver?

Comment: Can you give a full, running working example? It is not clear which modules you are importing.

Comment: I have a running example for firefox in which it opens a firefox window. Then I try chromium and it gives me that error message. I already have chromium installed.